# Weird non zero t-statistic when using statsmodels.formula.api.ols

Tags: python, regression, statsmodels

So I am currently using the stats models api to calculate alphas and betas for some returns in a research project. Basically I am creating a data frame that will contain mean returns, ..., alphas and betas for various investment strategies and compare those indicators to the overall market.

During this, as a formality, I wanted to calculate alpha and beta for the market return (on itself). As you can see in the image below the beta is 1 as expected, but the alpha (here intercept) and its t-statistic are non-zero. How can that be?

[Exhibit 1a](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b5Wk6.png)

Here is a mre:

```
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf
a=pd.DataFrame([2,3,2,3,2,2,2])
a.columns=["bla"]
model = smf.ols("bla ~ bla", data=a).fit()
model.summary()
```

Comment: Isn't this just a numerical error? Your coefficient is practically zero (1e-19), your standard error is practically zero (3.4e-19) but they are both so small that their division returns a small t.

Comment: I hope so, but why aren't they zero? is that a system limitation, a software bug or sth else.

Comment: Yes, the precision of the numbers computers use is limited. What we have is approximations. These approximations generally work well but small errors can propagate and lead to large errors in some cases. Since your demo is a rare edge case I wouldn't worry that much about it.